# How to find factors of factors of a number n times

Tags: java, recursion

Suppose I have a number 10
Step 1 : Find factors of 10 -> 1,2,5,10
Step 2 : I need to find the factors for each 1,2,5,10. So it will be array -> 1,1,2,1,5,1,2,5,10
Step 3 : Now I need to keep finding the factor of every number in the array
This will go on n times.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done with minimum time and space

Comment: What you want as result all the factors, there may be duplicates. Are you want a set of factors? or just total number of factors ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your own `factor` function that finds the factors of one number
2. Use `flatMap` to apply your function to an array of numbers
3. Loop over step 2 (with a simple for loop) to repeat it `n` times.

See the doc for `flatMap`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Write a method with the following signature.

```
public List<Integer> generateFactors(List<Integer> numbers)
```

Step 2: Call this method N times.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(10);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    numbers = generateFactors(numbers);
}
```

Step 3: Print the List.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```